# Merging two arrays using Jq command

Tags: linux, jq, array-merge

I have the following JSON object that I want to merge. So the scenario is `ticketId` and `requester_id` should become an attribute of each objects in `componentsByProdTourId` array.
Here is the input JSON data.

```json
{
  "componentsByProdTourId": [
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "France",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "ABC",
            "attributeType": "xyx"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "France",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "EFG",
            "attributeType": "lmn"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "FLC",
            "attributeType": "omp"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "ticketData": {
    "ticketId": "1234",
    "requester_id": "99885"
  }
}
```

The desired out I am looking for:

```json
{
  "componentsByProdTourId": [
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "France",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "ABC",
            "attributeType": "xyx"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ticketId": 1234,
      "requester_id": 99885
    },
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "France",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "EFG",
            "attributeType": "lmn"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ticketId": 1234,
      "requester_id": 99885
    },
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "FLC",
            "attributeType": "omp"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ticketId": 1234,
      "requester_id": 99885
    }
  ],
  "ticketData": {
    "ticketId": "1234",
    "requester_id": "99885"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

I tried this Jq command:

```
.componentsByProdTourId |= map(. + {ticketId: .ticketData.ticketId, requester_id: .ticketData.requester_id})
```

But the result was not ideal. `ticketId` and `requester_id` were null. Here is the output:

```json
{
  "componentsByProdTourId": [
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "France",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "ABC",
            "attributeType": "xyx"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ticketId": null,
      "requester_id": null
    },
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "France",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "EFG",
            "attributeType": "lmn"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ticketId": null,
      "requester_id": null
    },
    {
      "region": "Europe",
      "compSpec": {
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "FLC",
            "attributeType": "omp"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ticketId": null,
      "requester_id": null
    }
  ],
  "ticketData": {
    "ticketId": "1234",
    "requester_id": "99885"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.componentsByProdTourId[] += .ticketData
```

is enough. Your version is failing because at the time when you try to access `.ticketData`, `.` is the item you're mapping over, and not the root object. You could fix that by using `as` to capture `.ticketData`, but there's an easier way which is to skip `map` entirely.

Comment: Hi @hobbs can you give me a complete command? I am not an expert in Jq.

Comment: @JehanzebAfridi `jq '.componentsByProdTourId[] += .ticketData' blah.json`